# Responsive menu, iPad landscape mode dillema

Tags: ios, css, ipad, drop-down-menu, responsive-design

So I dont know if this question will be accepted here. But I'm facing a dillema and im looking for the best approach for the situation.

The situation is this, I'm designing a responsive website that has a navigation menu with dropdown items. I have triggered the alternative responsive menu to appear at 960px, which seems like the norm. But when viewing the website in an ipad in landscape mode, the normal menu will appear, which means that the dropdown items are not really available to the user.

Should I trigger the responsive menu at a higher resolution (1024px)? This seems very unnatural to me because 1024px is a desktop resolution. But If I dont trigger the alternative menu, the user will be deprived of available menu items.

What is the correct approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a stack overflow question.

The issue is less to do with resolution break-points in your CSS and more to do with how the site, specifically the navigation, works with touch devices like the Ipad in landscape mode. This is not the only device though, the Fire, Nexus tablets, and Galaxy Tab's in landscape mode will trigger the 1024px breakpoint.

My advice would be to make the navigation work for touch devices at 1024 resolution.